# Are there interest rate swaps that are not OTC?

Tags: interest-rate, swaps, over-the-counter

a. Are there any interest rate swaps that are **not** classified as OTC ? Could you please give an example. For example: spot starting, benchmark starting, broken dated, etc

b. Where is that classification defined, ie what determines if a rates product is OTC or not? Understand that the fact that there is a ticker on Bloomberg is not important to this determination.

c. Would the OTC status be partially determined whether a product is listed as available for trading on a specific venue, limiting to Bloomberg again as an example: BETP, BMTF, BSEF, BGL, etc

Comment: Could you elaborate on what prompted this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, options and futures are the only listed derivatives.

While some swaps are cleared, they're all traded OTC.

The distinction between OTC vs listed mainly comes down to standardization and which contracts are listed by CBOE, NYMEX, CME, etc.